# Constellation diagram of an 8 PSK with a \$\cos(\omega _ct)\$ reference oscillator

Tags: oscillator, digital-modulation, reference

[image]

[image]
[image]

Please help me with this problem in Tomasi's book for digital modulation. After getting the summer output, I got confused about what to draw in the constellation diagram.

According to my prof, since the reference signal changed, that means that my zero of the x-axis instead of a sine that should be where the cos(ω<sub>c</sub>t) comes in and the rest of the plot changes in accordance to this change (it's like rotating to right I suppose).

I got confused about where to base the phase shift of each summer output, since using arctan on all of them gives me only two answers; I don't know if I was wrong.

Also, the plot of the output doesn't make sense in the diagram. For example, using arctan for 000, I got -67.5°, but it isn't -67.5° anywhere in the constellation diagram relative to cos(ω<sub>c</sub>t) (the new positive x-axis). Below is also my answer for the plot of 000 bit sequence, please tell me if I got it right or not.

Comment: Homework type question require significant effort shown in solving the problem by yourself so that someone can figure out where you went wrong in your analysis.

Comment: ok thanks for the suggestion