# Constellation diagram of an 8-PSK modulator with \$\cos(\omega _ct)\$ as reference oscillator

Tags: homework, phase-shift, digital-modulation, reference

For the figure and problem below, is my 000 input plotted correctly and has the correct phase angle in my constellation diagram?

The cos(ω<sub>c</sub>t) is located on the positive x-axis since according to my prof it is the new reference and therefore be at the zero.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This question looks strangely familiar: [Constellation diagram of an 8 PSK with a \$\cos(\omega _ct)\$ reference oscillator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/639996/constellation-diagram-of-an-8-psk-with-a-cos-omega-ct-reference-oscillat)

Comment: because they are the same.

Comment: As I remember someone suggested to add my work on the problem, that's why  I did.

Comment: If both questions are about the same subject, please edit the original question, and remove this one.

Comment: @EarlyJunTagsip If you look for it, you should find a Gray-coded 8-PSK constellation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-shift_keying#Higher-order_PSK). What about that doesn't fit your own circumstances? (I love Lie groups and algebras. It's a personal area due to its application in M-theory.)

Comment: I am not sure if the plotted bit sequence came from a cos signal. And it doesn't really answer my question if my constellation diagram is correct sir/Ma'am.